# Bundler error when installing geniusgui-acs.

Tags: bundle

[root@localhost genieacs-gui]# bundle

```
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, andinstalling your bundle as
root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Using rake 11.2.2
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using minitest 5.9.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using pkg-config 1.1.7
Using rack 2.0.1
Using nio4r 1.2.1
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 7.1.0
Using byebug 9.0.5
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using thor 0.19.1
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using ffi 1.9.14
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.7
Using puma 3.5.2
Using bundler 1.13.6
Using sass 3.4.22
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using spring 1.7.2
Using sqlite3 1.3.11
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.8
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using sprockets 3.6.3
Using websocket-driver 0.6.4
Using mime-types 3.1
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 3.0.0
Using rb-inotify 0.9.7
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/local/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161209-28728-12avihx.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
generator.c: En la función ‘generate_json’:
generator.c:861:25: error: ‘rb_cFixnum’ no se declaró aquí (primer uso en esta función)
     } else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
                         ^
generator.c:861:25: nota: cada identificador sin declarar se reporta sólo una vez para cada función en
el que aparece
generator.c:863:25: error: ‘rb_cBignum’ no se declaró aquí (primer uso en esta función)
     } else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {
                         ^
generator.c: En el nivel principal:
cc1: aviso: no se reconoce la opción de línea de órdenes "-Wno-self-assign" [activado por defecto]
cc1: aviso: no se reconoce la opción de línea de órdenes "-Wno-constant-logical-operand" [activado por
defecto]
cc1: aviso: no se reconoce la opción de línea de órdenes "-Wno-parentheses-equality" [activado por
defecto]
cc1: aviso: no se reconoce la opción de línea de órdenes "-Wno-tautological-compare" [activado por
defecto]
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0-static/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'm using ruby 2.4.0preview, rails 5.0.0.1, node v0.10.18 in CentOS Linux 7.2.1.5.11.

My issue is that when I try to execute the command bundler, appears this error. 
I'm kinda lost. Any suggestion?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you are running `bundler` as `sudo`. That, in some cases, may cause problems. Last week I had a problem too because someone did that

**Second**, see why is it failing. In the end you have the clue: `Make sure that "gem install json -v '1.8.3'" succeeds before bundling.` That means just to type `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` in the terminal

**Third**, ruby version 2.4.0 is not supported neither in v1.0 or v1.1 of GenieACS. They both support 2.3.X

**Fourth**, if you are installing GenieACS v1.0, node v0.10.X will do, but if you are installing v1.1, then it will only work with node version v6.X

Hope you have a good time with GenieACS! :)

PS. I wrote a guide for GenieACS in Ubuntu 14.04 here: https://github.com/zaidka/genieacs/wiki/Installation-in-Ubuntu-14.04-Server,-64-bit
It will install v1.0, but that will become outdated in some months. I'm currently developing another guide for v1.1 in Debian 8.